# ExtJS 4.2 textfield set text with two colours

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Is there a way to insert in a textfield the next value:

Random (1234)

But in the textfield visualize it as follows:

[image]

Because I retrieve the information from the server as follows:

`"property1" : "Random (<span style='color:red;'>1234</span>)`

And the textfield is inside a form, and when I retrieve the information I use `loadRecord` to load the data into the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is impossible to use "Ext.form.field.Text" to show colored text.
But you can use display field (read only) or html editor..

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
            title: 'Form',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 550,
            height: 250,
            frame: true,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'htmleditor',
                fieldLabel: "HTML Editor",
                enableColors: false,
                enableAlignments: false,
                value: "Random (<span style='color:red;'>1234</span>)",
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: "Display Field",
                value: "Random (<span style='color:red;'>1234</span>)",
            }]
        });
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this solution